# How to lock the control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In window base application whenever right click on the control which give the option for lock control, asp.net give any facility for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no lock control option in ASP.NET , although you can provide absolute positioning for all the controls. From designer select the control, Go to Format -> Position... -> Positioning Stype - Provide absolute positioning